# Android app communicate with Node.Js server and MongoDB

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb

I am building a login in my android app. I am trying to make to make my app communicate with a Node.JS server using volley to make network request. The node.js server is already setup and is running. I made sure that my PC and my android phone are on the same network (I really don't know if this is necessary). Also Mongo DB is setup and running. But I get an error response when I try to login. This is my code:

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String getLoginEmail = loginEmail.getText().toString();
            String getLoginPassword = loginPassword.getText().toString();

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(getLoginEmail) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(getLoginPassword)) {
                loginUser(getLoginEmail, getLoginPassword);
            } else if...
        }
    });...


private void loginUser(final String gottenLoginEmail, final String gottenLoginPassword) {
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.logging_in));
    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    progressDialog.show();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.i("onResponse", response);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                Log.i("Response", response); //logged response

                //check if response at first position (index 0) equals success
                if (jsonObject.names().get(0).equals("success")) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                    finish();
                } else {
                    ...
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.i("Exception", e.getMessage()); //logged exception
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.login_activity), e.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.i("Error", "ERRROR: " + error.getMessage()); //logged error. Refer to debugger image below
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.login_activity), error.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("email", gottenLoginEmail);
            params.put("password", gottenLoginPassword);
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestHandler.getInstance(LoginActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}
```

In my Constants Java Class I have the following:

```
public class Constants {

public static final String ROOT_URL = "http://192.168.43.1:5000/api/user/auth/";
public static final String URL_LOGIN = ROOT_URL + "signin";
public static final String URL_REGISTER = ROOT_URL + "signup";

//192.168.43.1 is the DHCP server of the network my pc and android phone is connected to
//5000 is the node.js application port i.e. localhost:5000

}
```

Please I need help. I have been battling with this for 3 days now...

When I run the app I get this in the debugger console

[image]

N.B. "localhost:5000/api/user/auth/signin" is the API endpoint login route.

Answer (score 0):

I think your trouble is Firewall try to disable it 
if your OC is windows follow this guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dlBgoVMXIWo

Comment: I still got the same error after disabling firewall

Comment: do you think my URL is correct. I feel perhaps the problem is from my URL. I have tried using http://192.168.43.1:5000/api/user/auth/... ,  http://192.168.43.1/localhost:5000/api/user/auth/... , http://localhost:5000/api/user/auth/... , http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/user/auth/... , http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/user/auth/... , respectively as my URL's I still get the "Failed to connect error"